# calling the same function multiple times while clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which accepts a string and outputs it one character at a time with a delay. The event occurs when the user clicks a link or button. The problem is that if the user clicks a link and then another before the first one is done, they both run at the same time and output to the screen. It becomes jumbled up.
ex:
string1 : "i like pie very much"
string1 : "so does the next guy"
output  : i sloi kdeo epse .... and so on.

Anyone know a method to fix this?
I think I need a way to check if the function is being processed already, then wait till it is done before starting the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place both functions inside an object (because globals are bad), add a variable to the object which knows if a function is executing, and check the variable, like this:

```
var ns = {
    isExecuting:false,
    func1: function(){
       if (this.isExecuting) { return; }
       this.isExecuting = true;
       //do stuff 1
       this.isExecuting = false;        
    },
    func2: function(){
       if (this.isExecuting) { return; }
       this.isExecuting = true;
       //do stuff 2
       this.isExecuting = false;        
    }
}
```

and for extra elegance:

```
var ns = {
    isExecuting:false,
    executeConditionally:function(action){
       if (this.isExecuting) { return; }
       this.isExecuting = true;
       action();
       this.isExecuting = false; 
    }
    func1: function(){
        this.executeConditionally(function(){
          //stuff
        })       
    },
    func2: function(){
        this.executeConditionally(function(){
          //stuff
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for a good explanation about using a closure to avoid polluting your page.

Comment: thanks, i tried a simpler version and it doesn't seem to be working with a recursive function, but its a good start to working on a method.

Comment: Ok, I had to set the isRunning variable to false in front of each recursion call. it works now, but I was thinking of more along the lines of delaying the second string output instead if not running it at all. everything else that runs when the link is clicked still functions on click.  I will probably recode it later to stop the delay function and output what is left of the string instantly when the user clicks again.  Thank you all for the help though

Comment: just an update: I used a combination of this method and a settimeout function on my buttons to fix this. everything works perfectly for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

add a variable globally or in scope outside the method called `IsProcessing` and set it to true the first time the method is called, on the method you can then just check `if (IsProcessing) return false;`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set a variable that indicates whether the function is running:

```
var isRunning = false;

$('a').click(function({
    if(isRunning == false){
         isRunning = true;
         ///Do stuff
         isRunning = false;
    }
    else{
         return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want all the clicks to be taken into account, but in order ?
If so, I suggest you separate streams between adding a click to process, and consuming clicks
 :

the html :

```
<a class="example" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delayPushLine();">i like pie very much</a><br/>
<a class="example" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delayPushLine();">so does the next guy</a>
<div class="writeThere"></div>
```

and the javascript (using jQuery a bit)

```
var charDisplayDelay = 50; // the time between each char display
var displayDelay = 2000; // the time before a click is handled
var lines = [];
var lineIdx = 0, pos = 0;

function delayPushLine(e) {
    if (!e) {
        e = window.event
    }
    setTimeout(function() { lines.push(e.srcElement.innerText); }, displayDelay);
}

function showLines () {
    if (lines.length > lineIdx) {
        if (pos < lines[lineIdx].length) {
            $(".writeThere").append(lines[lineIdx].substr(pos,1));
            pos++;
        } else {
            pos = 0;
            lineIdx++;
             $(".writeThere").append("<br/>");
        }
    }
}

setInterval("showLines()", charDisplayDelay);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kD4JL/1/